# Print elements from JSON file in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

So I have to return every unique locality (cf. city) along with how often it occurs from a JSON file. I uploaded the JSON file into python but I'm having a hard time returning the locality and its occurrences.

Heres my code for importing json into my python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
with open('data.json') as json_file:      
   json_file = json_file.readlines()
   json_file = list(map(json.loads, json_file))
```

heres the first line of the json data file:

```
{'payload': {'existence_full': 1,
  'geo_virtual': '["56.9459720|-2.1971226|20|within_50m|4"]',
  'latitude': '56.945972',
  'locality': 'Stonehaven',
  '_records_touched': '{"crawl":8,"lssi":0,"polygon_centroid":0,"geocoder":0,"user_submission":0,"tdc":0,"gov":0}',
  'address': 'The Lodge, Dunottar',
  'email': 'dunnottarcastle@btconnect.com',
  'existence_ml': 0.5694238217658721,
  'domain_aggregate': '',
  'name': 'Dunnottar Castle',
  'search_tags': ['Dunnottar Castle Aberdeenshire', 'Dunotter Castle'],
  'admin_region': 'Scotland',
  'existence': 1,
  'category_labels': [['Landmarks', 'Buildings and Structures']],
  'post_town': 'Stonehaven',
  'region': 'Kincardineshire',
  'review_count': '719',
  'geocode_level': 'within_50m',
  'tel': '01569 762173',
  'placerank': 65,
  'longitude': '-2.197123',
  'placerank_ml': 37.27916073464469,
  'fax': '01330 860325',
  'category_ids_text_search': '',
  'website': 'http://www.dunnottarcastle.co.uk',
  'status': '1',
  'geocode_confidence': '20',
  'postcode': 'AB39 2TL',
  'category_ids': [108],
  'country': 'gb',
  '_geocode_quality': '4'},
 'uuid': '3867aaf3-12ab-434f-b12b-5d627b3359c3'}
```

I wrote this and many other codes but I keep getting errors that I must call an integer not a string:

```
for i in range (0, len (json_file)):
    print (json_file['paylod'][i]['locality'])
```

Comment: Your code assumes `json_file['payload']` is an array (p.s. - im assuming you meant payload not paylod) whereas your JSON shows that the key `payload` is not an array

Answer (score 0):

Dont use library "json"
USE: pickle is faster and it works

This should work:

```
 example = open(filename, 'rb')
 toprint = _pickle.load(example, encoding='latin1')
 print(toprint)
```

Comment: so where you wrote "_pickle.load(example, encoding='latin1')" do I write 'locality' for example so it tells me all the locality?

Comment: what you mean by locality ,is only charset which is coded file